# Opening another MATLAB session using system command fails

Tags: bash, matlab, terminal, system, launch

I have weird behavior when I try to open a second instance of MATLAB from inside a MATLAB command line. Namely, if I open a MATLAB and launch a second MATLAB like this:

```
    !/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/matlab
```

it works fine.

However, when I try to launch it with the ampersand like this (so it doesn't block up the original MATLAB )

```
    !/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/bin/matlab &
```

the second MATLAB at first starts loading, then dies.

My MATLAB as you see is 2012b

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: The behaviour is reproducible in R2014b as well.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem but had similar issues with `!` behaving unexpected. I ended up writing every command into a script file and call it via `system`

Comment: Try adding the option `-desktop` to the Matlab call.